# SQL join for A, B, distinct C

Tags: sql, database, join

I would appreciate some help on creating the proper SQL to retrieve only one value for matching records in my 3rd table "table C" as shown below.  Table A lists customers ID, name and state.  Table B lists foreign key customers ID and member card number.  Table C lists sales for member card number.

```
select  A.cifno, A.cfna1, A.cfstate, B.hbmast.cifno, B.hbmast.hbcid,  C.cast(ewmast.ewcid as dec(12,0)) as "eWire ID"
from library.cfmast cfmast join library.hbmast hbmast
on cfmast.cfcif# = hbmast.cifno left join library.ewmast ewmast
on hbmast.hbcid = cast(ewmast.ewcid as dec (12,0))
```

Sample data:

```
table A
**A.cifno, A.cfna1, A.cfstate**
J00022, John, OH
B00019, Ben, TX


table B
**B.hbmast.cifno, B.hbmast.hbcid**
J00022, 555500001234
B00019, 555500007878


table C
**ewmast.ewcid**
555500001234
555500001234
555500001234
555500007878
```

Desired output is:

```
J00022, John, OH, J00022, 555500001234, 555500001234
B00019, Ben, TX, B00019, 555500007878, 555500007878
```

-- NOT --

```
J00022, John, OH, J00022, 555500001234, 555500001234
J00022, John, OH, J00022, 555500001234, 555500001234
J00022, John, OH, J00022, 555500001234, 555500001234
B00019, Ben, TX, B00019, 555500007878, 555500007878
```

Comment: Did you hear about `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the keyword `distinct` in your select.

I.e., something like:

```
select distinct ....
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a date format statement in there that made distinct always throw an error, removed and all is better.
    date(digits(datfld7)) as "New Date"

Answer (score 2):

Voilá...

```
select DISTINCT A.cifno, A.cfna1, A.cfstate, B.hbmast.cifno, B.hbmast.hbcid,          C.cast(ewmast.ewcid as dec(12,0)) as "eWire ID"
from library.cfmast cfmast join library.hbmast hbmast
on cfmast.cfcif# = hbmast.cifno left join library.ewmast ewmast
on hbmast.hbcid = cast(ewmast.ewcid as dec (12,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DISTINCT operator

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

On your left join to Table C, you would want to put a "not null" clause. This would ensure that only the matching rows are displayed, otherwise they are ignored. Just saying.